# AngularJS does not read table values

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms

I am trying to implement a table where you could edit information of a user. The information is retrieved from database and I want to update the database with new variables. The problem is when I press the editbutton and try to pass my new variables from form, it does not read it, but when I add the button inside the column it reads the variables.

For e.g. In the code currently it reads the trainee.TraineesID and passes it through to my controller, the others are undefined. If I add the button inside the input form, it retrieved the information and passes it to the controller.

Is there a way to retrieve all the information from the forms and pass it to controller?

The code is:

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="trainee in trainees | filter : filterTrainee">
        <td ng-if="!editClicked">{{trainee.Name}}</td>
        <td ng-if="editClicked"><input type="text" name="Name" ng-init="nameInput=trainee.Name" ng-model="nameInput" placeholder="Name"></td>
        <td ng-if="!editClicked">{{trainee.Surname}}</td>
        <td ng-if="editClicked"><input type="text" name="Surname" ng-model="surnameInput" ng-init="surnameInput=trainee.Surname" placeholder="Surname"></td>
        <td ng-if="trainee.Status_TraineeID==1&&!editClicked">Deployed</td>
        <td ng-if="trainee.Status_TraineeID==2&&!editClicked">Training</td>
        <td ng-if="trainee.Status_TraineeID==3&&!editClicked">On Bench</td>
        <td ng-if="editClicked"><select name ="Status" ng-model="statusInput" placeholder="Select">
        <option value="1">Deployed</option>
        <option value="2">Training</option>
        <option value="3">Bench</option>
        </select></td>
        <td ng-if="!editClicked">{{trainee.Email}}</td>
        <td ng-if="editClicked"><input type="text" name="Email" ng-init="emailInput=trainee.Email" ng-model="emailInput" placeholder="Email"></td>
        <td ng-if="!editClicked">{{trainee.PhoneDetails}}</td>
        <td ng-if="editClicked"><input type="text" name="Phone" ng-init="phoneInput=trainee.PhoneDetails" ng-model="phoneInput" placeholder="Phone"></td>
        <td align="justify"><a ng-click="editClicked=!editClicked" class="btn pull-right"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a></td>
        <td align="justify" ng-if="!editClicked"><a ng-click="deleteTrainee(trainee.TraineesID)" class="btn pull-right"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></a></td>
        <td align="justify" ng-if="editClicked"><a ng-click="editTrainee(trainee.TraineesID, nameInput, surnameInput, statusInput, emailInput, phoneInput)" class="btn pull-right"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: I think creating a form object would help:  $scope.trainee_form = {}.  Then for your ng-model, use trainee_form.nameInput, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much Rob. The problem is solved by assigning the ng-module to the scope. I used `ng-init="editTrainee.nameInput=trainee.Name" ng-model="editTrainee.nameInput"`
" and to pass variables `ng-click="editTrainee(trainee.TraineesID, editTrainee.nameInput)`